# Can I overload a URL to return multiple subfolders in a calculated column?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have two images that are both located in my site assets folder and I want to show the two images based on when a source column returns "yes" or "no".

I have a  wrapped around a nested if statement and the only results I'm getting is the first image, "yes.png". Even if the source column displays "no" the calculated column returns the "yes.png" image.

Example:

```
="<DIV> <IMG src='/SiteAssets/yes.png'"&IF([Source Column]= "Yes", "yes.png",IF([Calculated Column]= "No", "no.png"))&"'> </DIV>
```

And if I leave IMG src as just `/SiteAssets` then I only get these:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
="<div><img src='/sites/<site-name>/SiteAssets/" & IF([Source Column] = "Yes", "yes.png", "no.png") & "'></div>"
```

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)